# How can I align form input to the bottom of the page with Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How can I align a bootstrap form input to the bottom of the page? I've tried several different approaches nothing has worked.

[How it currently looks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7YWR.png)

[How I want it too look.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMwRs.png)

I need to align the `form` element to the bottom to make it look like proper messaging input.

However, when I attempt to use `form { position: fixed; bottom: 0; }` it changes the formatting of the input [like so.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRebQ.png)

Thanks for the help.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 messages">
      <p class="city">Edinburgh Uni <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap"></i><i style="float:right" class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i></p>
      <p class="paddingLeft" style="margin-top:-15px"><i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i> Jack</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <h4 style="margin-top:20px">International Business  <i style="float:right" class="fa fa-cog"></i></h4>
      <p class="description"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> 10 | Support group for International Business Students class of 2019.</p>
      <hr>
      <form>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Message">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> position: absolute; bottom: 0;

use absolute position on the form, and place it 0 pixels from the bottom of its parent; 
make sure the parent container (col-md-9) has an appropriate height for this to work.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I've updated the question to show what happens when I try using this CSS.

Comment: Add left and right CSS properties to ensure it takes up the whole width of the container. Here's a test: https://jsfiddle.net/gLw9bj7n/5/
also added a min-height to the container to demonstrate the positioning taking place.

Comment: Thanks @jcruz this solution worked perfectly. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Try this (use position that is the most appropriate to you):

```
form { position: fixed; bottom: 0; }
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I've updated the question to show what happens when I try using this CSS.

Comment: Looks like you are losing your width due to new `position: fixed`, try applying a `width: 100%` attribute to your style. If that's not gonna help, adding a snippet with the code example would be great benefit :)

Comment: I dont think he wants to use fixed position since that refers to being fixed positioned in reference to the window. I think what he's after is for it to be at the bottom of the container (col-md-9) so use absolute instead, as suggested in my answer.

Comment: _fixed_ is just an example of how to make it work. I will let @JMcMillan decide what he is after, based on the requirements we got, `width: 100%` should do the trick

Comment: Thanks @AlexAnanjev, appreciate your help!